# SSE3 instructions in F#

Tags: f#, sse

How do I parallelize my F# program using SSE3 instruction set? Does the F# compiler support it?

Comment: Can you use Mono instead of .Net?

Comment: I guess you are pointing towards Mono.Simd. But I ve to use .NET :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about this, but:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304020142/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/satnam_singh/archive/2010/10/14/f-black-scholes-running-on-gpis-and-sse3-multicore-processors-using-accelerator.aspx)

Comment: I think you have to use `X64Target` if you want it to make use of SSE instruction set.

Answer (score 3):

.Net doesn't talk to the hardware at that level. If you want explicit control over the instruction set used, you'll need to call out to a library written in a more appropriate language. C/C++ comes to mind.

Comment: so there is no equivalent of Mono.Simd library in .NET?

Comment: No, because Mono.Simd relies on changes to the JIT compiler

Answer (score 0):

Probably not useful, but you can play with the internal fields on a delegate to make it call to arbitrary code: http://www.atrevido.net/blog/2005/01/28/Inline+X86+ASM+In+C.aspx

See the comments for more caveats and other approaches. The benefit of playing with a delegates target directly is (AFAIK) you won't get a managed-unmanaged transition as if you did GetDelegateForFunctionPointer or other interop approaches.

On the downside, this means you have to code it by hand and make sure the calling conventions line up and so on. It's probably fragile, and the delegate call overhead might make it not worth it.